# Session to save "email" not passing onto confirmation page because of form.php

Tags: php, session

This is my process.
Ive attached a link to each page so you can see the exact code since its important.
I cant solve this problem.

[page.php](http://pastie.org/2708301) (where the form resides on, its at the bottom of the page)

[form.php](http://pastie.org/2708321) (where the this form and others are processed and the data is saved into the CRM)

[confirmation.php](http://pastie.org/2708307) (where page.php redirects on after POST submit)

Basically i have a form on page.php that form POSTS to form.php where the data is saved into a CRM script and then redirects to confirmation.php.

I need to pass the "email" value onto confirmation.php 
What i did was i used a session on form.php to save the email value and then echo it on confirmation. Please check the code above to see how.

But the result? Its not working, the email is not being echoed on confirmation.php

Any ideas?

Importants part of the codes above (in my opinion):

On form.php at the very top:

```
<?php 
session_start();    
$_SESSION['contact'] = $_POST['email']; 
?>
<?php
```

On confimation.php at the very top:

```
<?php 
session_start(); 
?>
<?php
```

on confirmation.php i then echo it:

```
<?php echo $_SESSION['contact']; ?>
```

But its not working.

Comment: We simply cannot read 2.000.000 lines of code. Just post or link the most important part of them.

Comment: I posted the links because maybe i consider important something that is not enough and maybe im leaving anything important out.

Let me see if i can point some important thing thanks

Comment: @AurelioDeRosa done, please check again to see if u can discover something and thanks very much.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. Well, first of all i suggest you to do a var_dump in the page.php and the confirmation.php to see what they echo.

Comment: what i did was i printed the session on form.php and it did print the email but not on confirmation

Comment: What you see in the var_dump? NULL?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4312/discussion-between-aurelioderosa-and-sebas)

Comment: You need to be a bit more specific to the code which you think is incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add the email address to the query string for the thank you URL.

Assuming the thank you URL doesn't already have variables in the query string, then this is all you have to do:

In form.php, change this:

```
if ($thanksurl) {
  header('Location: ' . $thanksurl);
}
```

To this:

```
if ($thanksurl) {
  $thanksurl .= '?email=' . $email;
  header('Location: ' . $thanksurl);
}
```

If there's already variables in the URL, then you'd want the additional line to look like this, with an ampersand instead of a question mark:

```
$thanksurl .= '&email=' . $email;
```